# NavMesh.CalculatePath returns invalid path Unity3D

Tags: unity, path-finding, navmesh

I am trying to get coordinates for path from source to destination object using `NavMesh`. `NavMesh.CalculatePath()` is only working for one level surprisingly. For all others, it returns false. Also `NavMeshPathStatus` is invalid. [This](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/83882285/Working.png) is working Level, while [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/83882285/NotWorking.png) is not working fine with navmesh.

**Code:**

```
private NavMeshPath path;

    void Start () {
        path = new NavMeshPath();
    }

//Following function is called on button press
public void giveHint() {

        NavMesh.CalculatePath(source.transform.position, destination.transform.position, NavMesh.AllAreas, path);


    if (path.status == NavMeshPathStatus.PathComplete)
        print ("Path complete");
    else if (path.status == NavMeshPathStatus.PathInvalid)
        print ("Path invalid");
    else if (path.status == NavMeshPathStatus.PathPartial)
        print ("Path partial");

    for (int i = 0; i < path.corners.Length-1; i++) {
            Debug.Log(path.corners[i]);
        }
   }

// Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
    if (path.corners != null) {
            if(path.corners.Length > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < path.corners.Length-1; i++) {
                Debug.DrawLine (path.corners [i], path.corners [i + 1], Color.red);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Please tell me way to debug/solve this issue. How unity calculates path between source and destination? Can there be possibly blockage in path? If yes then how? How path is invalid? Is there any bottleneck with the usage of `CalculatePath` function? Need guide from you guys... Thanks!

Comment: Check what `CalculatePath` is returning.  If it's `false`, then it was unable to find a path.

Comment: could you somehow display your navmesh? the one working and one which isn't? Or check the way you initialize the navmesh in other levels

Comment: @GuntherFox It is returning false. Just checked :(

Comment: I never used navmeshes but I assume that you somehow set up in the scene view and have properties in the inspector. maybe a print screen of that and also of the shape in the scene view could be of help

Comment: @Lara If it's returning `false` then my guess is there is some obstacle or obstruction.

Comment: [This](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/83882285/Working.png) is working level navmesh. [This](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/83882285/NotWorking.png) is not working nav mesh @Leggy7 and Gunther

Comment: @GuntherFox Do you think there is any kind of obstacle? Because all walls have been marked as navigation static + Not walkable. Actually these are obstacle, but there is a way too in between the walls

Comment: have you checked if there is any floor marked  as non walkable?

Comment: @Lara Everything looks alright. The only thing I notice in the picture of the on that's not working in that there's a single triangle that looks a different shade of blue from the rest (down from where the white cube is).

Comment: @GuntherFox I just checked, that was because of shadow. I moved the walls and baked again, that light blue color disappeared. Still no path found.

Comment: @Leggy7 I haven't marked any floor individual. It is whole terrain marked as walkable

Comment: @NightFury  Have you tried using different source and destination positions to rule out and sort of bugs?  Try placing them right next to each other and then each time, move the destination slightly along the path you know is correct until you find wherever it fails and that might help you find out what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I figured out where I was wrong. I have a cube gameobject as destination. I was not making it part of navmesh baking. `Navigation Static` was not marked for it. So when navmesh was baked, destination was not included as part of it, so path status was invalid.

I cleared the navmesh, made my cube `Navigation Static` and `Walkable`, baked the navmesh again. Now I am getting valid path for all my levels.

[image]

Hope it helps someone!